Unit fails - Missing mocked calls
Issue: Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock
io.mockk.MockKException: Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock
My code:
@Test
fun testGetRocketsEmitsOnNullData() = runTest {
    val mockData = mockk<RocketsQuery.Data> {
        every { rockets } returns emptyList()
    }
    val mockResponse = mockk<ApolloResponse<RocketsQuery.Data>>() {
        coEvery { data } returns mockData
    }
    val apolloClient = mockk<ApolloClient>()
    val repo = RocketsRepositoryImpl(apolloClient)
    coEvery { apolloClient.query(any<RocketsQuery>()).execute() } returns mockResponse
    val result = repo.getRockets().first()
    assertTrue(result.items.isEmpty())
}

Issue is here:
    coEvery { data } returns mockData

I use coEvery to use suspend functions.
I'm trying to fetch graphql data and test null values.

Normally, a Kotlin property has an implicit, compiler-generated getter. On the JVM, a property val data would have a Java method getData(). When you have coEvery { data } returns mockData, it is this getter method that would be mocked.
Unfortunately, in the case of ApolloResponse, data is a @JvmField. As such, it does not have a getter method, and so it can't be mocked.
To work around this limitation, you need to create your own dummy AppoloResponse instance using a Builder.
See also this issue: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/488
